# Assigning TypeScript property values with = vs :

Tags: angular, typescript, class, object, properties

I have the following `Angular` component:

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: `
  <div>{{getDisplayValue(value)}}</div>
  <button (click)="value= { display: 'one' }">1</button>
  <button (click)="value.display = 'two'">2</button>`
})
export class TestProblemButtonClickComponent implements OnInit {

  public value = {display: 'old'};

  public getDisplayValue(value): string {
    return value.display;
  }

  ...
}
```

Why is an `=` used after declaring the `public value` property? I'm used to seeing properties followed by a `:`, then the value. If I change the `=` to a `:`, I get some errors when I click button 2. If go into the `value` property's object and change  the `:` after `dislay` to a `=`, the code doesn't even run and I get the following error: `Did you mean to use a ':'? An '=' can only follow a property name when the containing object literal is part of a destructuring pattern.`

Can someone talk me through this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused between:

- JavaScript class member assignation (`public value = something`)
- JS object key value assignation (`{display: 'old'}`)
- TypeScript variable type declaration (`public value: valueType`)
- JavaScript "`{display = 'old'}`" means nothing, except in the context of a function argument destructuring with default value